# Excel formula to calculate orders placed per person within given timeframe of first order

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In column A I have the Person ID, in column B I have the dates (dd/mm/yyyy) on which that person has ordered a product.  For each person, I want to know the number of orders they placed that  were within 6 years of their first order. What excel formula could I use please?

Comment: Try `COUNTIFS()`

Comment: I have used Countifs(A:A,A2) and it counts the number of orders placed for each customer, but I don't know how to get it to select just the orders within 6 years of the first order date

Comment: Add another condition to check that the order date is within half year, `COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**To solve the problem *"First Order Date" & "Six Years Span Date"* has to be calculated.**

Write this Array formula in D3 to find *First Order Date*, finish this formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter then fill it down:

`{=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$14=C3,$B$3:$B$14))}`

In Cell E3 write this formula to count *Six Years Span Date* & fill it down:

`=DATE(YEAR(D3)+6,MONTH(D3),DAY(D3))`

Finally to count *number of orders* write this Formula in Cell E7 and fill it down:

`=COUNTIFS(A3:A14,"="&C3,B3:B14,">="&D3,B3:B14,"<="&E3)`

**N.B.**

- *Adjust the cell address according to your need.*

Comment: There's more than one person in col A and it needs to be on a per-person basis.

Comment: @fixer1234, OP said Person wise, so that I've shown for one only,, let me add the note to answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, now I've edited the answer for more than one person.

Comment: Instead of the array formula, you could also use the built-in `MINIFS` function. It's easier to use than an array, IMO. Same for the date, instead of rebuilding a `DATE`, you could add `6*365` days to the first order date, which can be faster if there are thousands and thousands of orders.

Comment: @piko, thanks for useful suggestions, I'll try it also.